# Vk_api Error 917. Бот не может отправить сообщения, все права ему выданы

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Учусь писать ботов для бесед Вконтакте.

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='мой токен')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'id группы')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
Lslongpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
Lsvk = vk_session.get_api()
vk.messages.send(chat_id='424', message='Сообщение', random_id=get_random_id())
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [917] You don't have access to this chat
```

Доступ к истории сообщений есть, права администратора тоже. В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chat_id` у тебя и у бота для одной и той же беседы отличаются! Они относительны для каждого пользователя/бота.

Для того, что бы узнать `chat_id` беседы, можно получить список [всех бесед](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations) и уже среди всех бесед найти необходимую и записать `id`.

```py
print(vk.messages.getConversations()['items'])
```

Можно пройтись по этому списку (там находятся [объекты бесед](https://vk.com/dev/objects/conversation)) и найти необходимую, например, по названию. Это уже зависит от ваших нужд.